# conexión remota a servidor mysql - ubuntu server

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

descargue **mysql-server** en ubuntu sever 16.04.3 estos son los paquetes que me instalo utilizando *sudo apt install mysql-server*

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
entonces estuve investigando como poder conectarse de manera remota al servidor mysql y vi que tenia que editar el archivo **/etc/mysql/my.cnf** y comentar la linea bind 127.0.0.1

el problema es que mi archivo **my.cnf** solo contiene estas 21 lineas
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

utilice también *sudo mysql-secure-installation* y obviamente utilice a la opción **no** en *Disallow root login remotely?* pero aun así no funciona.

entonces mi pregunta es ¿me falta algo por descargar e instalar? ¿porque el archivo my.cnf no parece estar configurado o tiene tan pocas lineas?

agradecería si alguien puede ser tan amable de ayudarme o darme una respuesta.

Comment: No se cual es tu caso pero si tienes un servidor sql y un servidor web y quieres conectarte a una base de datos tienes que usar en host la ip de tu servidor, puerto 3306 usuario tu usuario sql, ojo el usuario sql, y la contraseña que pusiste al instalar sql server, especifica mejor como quieres hacer tu conexion remota

Comment: Como detalle, despues de cambiar el archivo has reiniciado el servidor? prueba con sudo service mysqld restart (por si las moscas)

Comment: El archivo de configuración lo encuentras en: nano /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf Espero te ayude.

Comment: Tengo el mismo problema que Akira94 habilite puerto y 3306 y conecto con la ip de mi servidor modifique el archivo de configuración y no logro realizar la conexión a través de ODBC conexión remota de windows.
Si alguien puede comentar.
Muchas Gracias

Comment: Aquí está la solución, yo tenía el mismo problema y me funciono
Saludos https://www.sololinux.es/acceso-remoto-a-mysql-con-ubuntu/

Answer (score 0):

El archivo **my.cnf** esta incluyendo otros archivos de las carpetas **/etc/mysql/conf.d** y **/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/**.

La linea **bind-address = 127.0.0.1** se debe encontrar en un archivo dentro de **/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/**, no se cual sera exactamente, pero supongo que este archivo deber terminar con el nombre **-server.cnf**

Otra cosa que podrías hacer es agregar al final **bind-address = 0.0.0.0** de tu archivo **my.cnf**

Answer (score 0):

El usuario por el que te esta conectando debe tner permisos para la pc cliente o en su defecto todas los equipos.

para eso debes crear un usuario o darle permisos a algún usuario existente por ejemplo asignarlo a root:

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;

Answer (score -1):

En Ubuntu 18.04 modifique la linea **bind-address = 0.0.0.0** en el archivo **/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf**, luego reinicié el servicio ** sudo service mysql restart** y listo.

Probé usando MySQL Workbench.